# Wine can not handle system fonts

Tags: debian, wine, fontconfig, multiarch

Debian Jessie (amd64)
wine wine-1.6.2 (i386)

There are system fonts avalable for x-applications (truetype).
But i can not see them in font select dialogue in `wine`. `wine`-applications also can not use system fonts?

How to make `wine` use fonts wich installed in system?

Problem solved by installing `libfontconfig1:i386` package. As i can guess `wine` tried to get font list from `fontconfig`, but there were no i386-library.

Answer (score 2):

There's an answer to this on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86335/installing-other-fonts-on-wine), which says that fonts in `/usr/share/fonts` should be usable directly in Wine, but the default setup in Debian doesn't support this. As you point out yourself, getting that to work requires installing `libfontconfig1:i386` (this will be fixed in the next version of the Wine package, albeit probably not in Jessie...).

Alternatively, you can explicitly add fonts you want to use in Windows applications by either configuring them in the system registry (`system.reg` in your Wine prefix, usually `~/.wine`), or by copying (or linking) them to `C:\Windows\Fonts` in Wine (usually `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts/`).

Note that having lots of fonts available to Wine can make Windows applications very slow to start; it takes a long time to enumerate all the fonts.